# Short story that ends with people floating upwards

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Around 2016 I read a short story that I believe was published in an online publication similar to the New Yorker. I’ve been looking for it ever since.

A man works at a factory where he seems to be plotting something with a colleague. At the end of each day he returns home to his home where he lives with his parents. They play board games or maybe watch certain TV shows like clockwork (I think). At some point it becomes clear that his parents are dead. The story ends with everybody floating upwards into the sky like a mass ascension.

Does anyone have any idea what this might be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there somehow a link between the fact that dead people are still around and everyone floating away?  Are his parents somehow undead, or are they mechanically simulating their life?

Comment: Sounds like this might be somthing about the Christian Rapture.

Comment: Thank you! :) Good question. There might be the implication that they are in limbo, I guess? As far as I could tell nobody else in the story was dead. 

Not sure about the Rapture although that’s a good point. It was a ‘secular’ setting but it could be an allegorical thing. Might add it to my search.

Comment: Might well be something from or based on the [Left behind series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_Behind) by Tim LaHaye and Jerry Jenkins